# Firstly sort dictonary by values and if values are the same to sort in alphabetic order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I've got dictionary with {'text' : number}. Firstly, I need to sort dictionary by values and if values are the same to sort in alphabetical order. How to implement this?

Input:

```
dict = {"aaa" : 12, "ccc" : 13, "bbb" : 13, "ddd" : 11}
```

Output:

```
# ddd(11)  aaa(12)  ccc(13)  bbb(13)  -> sorting only by values

# ddd(11)  aaa(12)  bbb(13)  ccc(13) -> sorting second time also by alphabet, final result
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please follow the steps described here when editing your question [mre]

Comment: Sorting a dictionary with one element in it won't have much of an impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> d = {'aaa' : 12, 'ccc' : 13, 'bbb' : 13, 'ddd' : 11}
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1], t[0]))) # Sort by value then by key.
{'ddd': 11, 'aaa': 12, 'bbb': 13, 'ccc': 13}
```